# Efficiently extracting column of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I currently have a piece of code that I'm trying to optimise, and the bottleneck seems to be extracting a given column from a fairly large matrix.

In particular, my code spends 50% of its time doing Wi=W(:,minColIdx). I've also tried linear indexing, but there was no change.

I was wondering if anyone knows why this is the case, and if anyone has any tips that could help me optimise this part of my code.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/TnTy6a8D
It's really poorly optimised right now, I was just playing around a bit with gpuArray on my new GPU. Lines 44 and 53, where I try to extract columns from W, are where the code bottlenecks.

Comment: Would it be possible to share rest of the code too?

Comment: That part can hardly be optimized. As Divakar says, give us something more :-)

Comment: @Divakar I added my code to the original post. Thanks.

Comment: Line `44` that has `Wi=W(:,minColIdx)`, doesn't look like the bottleneck, but line `53` might be.

Comment: @Divakar Originally lines 44-46 had the same form as 53, but I split it up to find which part it was bottlenecking on. Lines 44-46 take approximately the same time as line 53. It spends roughly 25% each on these two parts.

Comment: How are you timing it? You are dealing with gpuArrays, so simple tic-tocs won't be enough I think.

Comment: I was using the MATLAB Profiler. I was just trying to use GPUArrays to speed up the matrix operations, since W can get quite big - however this bottleneck actually makes it run much slower than my original code.

Comment: As @LuisMendo already mentioned, the extracting part (what you ask about) simply cannot be optimized much. Check my answer for the basic thoughts on this.

Comment: My personal suggestion would be sticking to your CPU code and ask specific questions here about the bottlenecks with that CPU code. Also, it looks like `norm` is dragging you behind, for which look around on Stackoverflow for faster alternatives of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Can the speed of the operation be improved?

Of course

## Is it worth it to optimize the indexing code?

Probably not

---

Matlab is REALLY good at basic matrix operations (if doing it in C++ is 10% faster I would really be surprised). You can forget about finding a better way to index a matrix, if you really want a noticable performance increase improving your hardware is probably your best bet.

That being said, it is of course always worth thinking about whether you really need to do the heavy calculation that you are attempting, or whether you can think of a smarter algorithm.

Comment: +1 for **On-The-Face-Titles** :) On a serious note, I think `runtime` could be a better term instead of `speed` as we are dealing with GPUs anyway.

Comment: So you're saying that even in C++, doing such an operation would be slow? I was planning on rewriting my code to use CUDA rather than MATLAB's built-in GPU computing capabilities - and as far as I know, using elementwise operations would be preferable under CUDA/C++, so this issue would be circumvented.

Comment: @DanielCrane I would advise something like MAGMA, as it is GPU based and has those Linear Algebra functions available with it on the lines of LAPACK, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take at face value your statement about the bottleneck being extracting the column from a matrix since you don't provide enough detail for me to speculate otherwise, though I find this somewhat surprising.

If you have access to the matlab compiler, I suggest you try compiling your bottleneck function.  Try:

```
help mcc
```

From within that help you will see that a typical use is:

Make a stand-alone C executable for myfun.m:

```
mcc -m myfun
```

You could also try writing a c function to get your column and compile with mex:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I added my code to the original post, thanks.

Comment: Compiling self-written loops can sometimes be faster, however typically the builtin functions of matlab cannot be improved upon this way.

Comment: Whether or not you can improve on built-in function performance, it is often possible to get 10-100x speed improvements depending on self written code. The original question did not mention GPU; I agree that if you already are using the GPU, compiling code is probably not the answer.